Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running multiple jobs
With Spring Batch version 5.0.2, facing the following exception Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction. I'm having two jobs running in order through the JobLauncher.
Tried with adding the below property and no luck on it.
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.repository.isolationlevelforcreate=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE or ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
Also tried with adding below annotation
@EnableBatchProcessing(isolationLevelForCreate = "ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED")
Sporadically getting the exception Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction.
Thanks
